# Data frame splitting and plot map

Tags: pandas

I have implemented the following Code (Pandas) to plot map for each different category - Is there any way to improve the performance of this code? It takes lot of time to process for 100K records.

```
vehicleList = a2.vehicleId.unique()
timeList = a2.time.unique()
dayList = a2.day.unique()
seasonList = a2.season.unique()

for vehicle in vehicleList:
    for day in dayList:
        for time in timeList:
            for season in seasonList:
                tempDf = a2[(a2["vehicleId"] == vehicle)  & (a2["day"] == day) & (a2["time"] == time) & (a2["season"] == season)]
                if not tempDf.empty:
                    # # Plot Chart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know about timing without your specific data, but your code is equivalent to this code which at least seems simpler:

```
a2.groupby([vehicleList, timeLis, dayList, seasonList]).apply(lambda g: g.plot())
```

Comment: Happy it helped.